# Migration from asp.net to asp.net core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I've found following tutorial how to migrate form asp.net to asp.net core to run project on Linux:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/mvc

Unfortunately when I'm trying to "Configure Identity and Membership"
and I'm copying code to project looks like there are not such commands for .net core

For example, this part:

> Then, open Startup.cs and update the ConfigureServices() method to use
>   Entity Framework and Identity services:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  // Add EF services to the services container.
  services.AddEntityFramework(Configuration)
    .AddSqlServer()
    .AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>();

  // Add Identity services to the services container.
  services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(Configuration)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

  services.AddMvc();
}
```

The same situation is for ApplicationUser.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace NewMvc6Project.Models
{
  public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
  {
  }
}
```

and ApplicationDbContext.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFramework;
using Microsoft.Data.Entity;

namespace NewMvc6Project.Models
{
  public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
  {
    public ApplicationDbContext()
    {
      Database.EnsureCreated();
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptions options)
    {
      options.UseSqlServer();
    }
  }
}
```

Is it wrong tutorial or I supposed to install some new package?

Comment: are you saying there is no ConfigureService method in your startup? what is your issue?

Comment: NO no. I have ConfigureService method, but right now I dont know what to do in those cases:

http://scr.hu/2aps/nrpyr
http://scr.hu/2aps/g514u
http://scr.hu/2aps/ozpay
http://scr.hu/2aps/29zjc

Comment: `options.UseSqlServer();` and `OnConfiguring` in `ApplicationDbContext` is not required,
remove those, try to build and restart visual studio to see if the error disappears.

Comment: As @NucS said you do not need onConfiguing in you ApplicaitonDb, as for resolving the user I think you need to create it with an interface `public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser`

Answer (score 0):

I assumed you are using VS2015.
Because I'm trying in VS2017 some extension method has changed.

```
services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer();
```

Have you tried to upgrade the packages in NuGet ?

New web project in VS2017 is giving packages version 1.1.1 for ASP.NET Core
as a default, but VS2015 I think it's giving version 1.0.0